# Does installing a root package automatically install a scoped library?

Tags: npm

After I am installing a root library, such as `npm install aws-amplify`, sometimes it seems that I need to install its sub library such as `npm install @aws-amplify/cli`. Why did not `npm install aws-amplify` install every sub library within it?

What's the npm packaging and installing rule here? can someone help me clearing understand that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up 2 different syntaxes. The `@namespace/package` is relatively new. It used to be just `package`, and some packages still use this. In the old way package tend to name themselves 'namespace-package' as some sort ofworkaround.

But that is not your question. Your question is 'why do they even do this?'.

Why wouldn't you just download all the npm package out there? Then you have and can use everything, right? As you can imagine this doesn't make much sense, you will only want to download and use what you need. Think of this quote from Joe Armstrong:

> You wanted a banana but what you got was a gorilla holding the banana and the entire jungle.

The quote is a entirely out of context since it is more about not using classes, but it still kind of applies to this. At lot of packages will offer you a core package and the option to add sub-packages based on your need. Like in your example, someone might not need `@aws-amplify/cli`, this way he doesn't have to download it.